# C# .Net 5: Where are bindingNavigator and DataSet controls in Design Mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-5

My application is .Net 5 WinForm and it needs working with SQL DataBase.
But I don't see base WinForm components for working with DB in Visual Studio 2019 Toolbox window. I can't find here neither BindingNavigator nor DataSet, why? Data section in Visual Studio Toolbox for .Net app is very primitive, it contains only DataGridView and BindingSource. Moreover, BindingSource doesn't work, i can't assigne it with SQL Database.
What's going on?

P.S.: Everything works fine for outdated .Net Framework applications.

Comment: Perhaps you need to enable the designer? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/windows-forms-designer-for-net-core-released/

Comment: Have you tested the advise of `chadntd`, after I tested it, it runs perfectly.

Comment: @chadnt, I've tested your advice, VS2019 with latest updates and with preview designer, project is about MySQL Connecter: BindingNavigator and DataSet are absent, BindingSource still doesn't work (i can not select DataSource for it).

Answer (score 0):

i stucked in same situation, so i will write this for who will search in future.
apparently, binding source in .net framework 5 and 6 is not supported for winform or WFP. you had to work with old framework, if you wish to use it.
although,i did add a data-set to the project and it pull all the tables from server explorer window and create all data adabtor.
i will try it and update the post.